# Is there a Coldfusion alternative to the php function openssl_verify()?

Tags: php, coldfusion

Is there a coldfusion alternaitive to this php function: [openssl_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-verify.php):

> `openssl_verify()` verifies that the signature is correct for the
>   specified data using the public key associated with pub_key_id. This
>   must be the public key corresponding to the private key used for
>   signing.

I've looked all over but there doesn't seem to be any. Thanks in advance for any info?

Comment: I don't think there is a native CF function, but somebody may have submitted a udf to http://cflib.org/.

Comment: Cheers for the feedback, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no built in functions, AFAIK. However, java supports [signature verification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/index.html), which you could adapt with a bit of java code.

1. Convert the data you want to verify into binary. The exact steps depends on what you are verifying, but say it is a physical file:

   ```
   dataBytes = fileReadBinary( "c:\path\someFile.zip" );
   ```
2. Decode the signature value into binary. Again, the "how" depends on the signature format. If it is a base64 encoded string:

   ```
   signatureBytes = binaryDecode( base64SignatureString, "base64" );
   ```
3. Load the certificate from your keystore (or from a file) and extract the public key:

   ```
   // Example: "C:\ColdFusion\jre\lib\security\cacerts" 
   fis = createObject("java", "java.io.FileInputStream").init( pathToKeyStore );
   keyStore = createObject("java", "java.security.KeyStore").getInstance("JKS");
   // Default keystore password is "changeit" (do not keep the default. change it)
   keyStore.load(fis, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
   publicKey = keyStore.getCertificate( "yourCertAlias" ).getPublicKey();
   ```
4. Create a [Signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html) object to perform the verification. Initialize it with the appropriate algorithm (ie SHA1withRSA, etcetera), public key and the data to verify:

   ```
   sign = createObject("java", "java.security.Signature").getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
   sign.initVerify( publicKey );
   sign.update( dataBytes );
   ```
5. Finally, feed in the signature and verify its status:

   ```
   isVerified = sign.verify(signatureBytes);
   writeDump( isVerified );
   ```

For more details, see [Lesson: Generating and Verifying Signatures](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/index.html) and [Weaknesses and Alternatives](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/enhancements.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt using cfexecute along with the OpenSSL CLI. https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/verify.html